# Plotting plots in same cell

Tags: python, python-3.x, matplotlib, jupyter

This code renders two normal distributions :

```
from scipy.stats import norm
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import numpy as np

data = norm.rvs(10.0, 2.5, size=500)
mu, std = norm.fit(data)
plt.hist(data, bins=25, normed=True, alpha=0.6, color='g')
xmin, xmax = plt.xlim()
x = np.linspace(xmin, xmax, 100)
p = norm.pdf(x, mu, std)
plt.plot(x, p, 'k', linewidth=3)
title = "Fit results: mu = %.2f,  std = %.2f" % (mu, std)

plt.title(title)
fig = plt.gcf()
fig.set_size_inches(4, 3)

plt.show()

data = norm.rvs(10.0, 2.5, size=500)
mu, std = norm.fit(data)
plt.hist(data, bins=25, normed=True, alpha=0.6, color='g')
xmin, xmax = plt.xlim()
x = np.linspace(xmin, xmax, 100)
p = norm.pdf(x, mu, std)

plt.plot(x, p, 'k', linewidth=2)
title = "Fit results: mu = %.2f,  std = %.2f" % (mu, std)
plt.title(title)
fig = plt.gcf()
fig.set_size_inches(4, 3)

plt.show()
```

: 
[image]

How to renders these distributions side by side ?

I've tried using subplots :

```
fig, axs = plt.subplots(1,2)
```

So previous code becomes :

```
from scipy.stats import norm
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import numpy as np

fig, axs = plt.subplots(1,2)

data = norm.rvs(10.0, 2.5, size=500)
mu, std = norm.fit(data)
plt.hist(data, bins=25, normed=True, alpha=0.6, color='g')
xmin, xmax = plt.xlim()
x = np.linspace(xmin, xmax, 100)
p = norm.pdf(x, mu, std)
plt.plot(x, p, 'k', linewidth=3)
title = "Fit results: mu = %.2f,  std = %.2f" % (mu, std)

plt.title(title)
fig = plt.gcf()
fig.set_size_inches(4, 3)

plt.show()

data = norm.rvs(10.0, 2.5, size=500)
mu, std = norm.fit(data)
plt.hist(data, bins=25, normed=True, alpha=0.6, color='g')
xmin, xmax = plt.xlim()
x = np.linspace(xmin, xmax, 100)
p = norm.pdf(x, mu, std)

plt.plot(x, p, 'k', linewidth=2)
title = "Fit results: mu = %.2f,  std = %.2f" % (mu, std)
plt.title(title)
fig = plt.gcf()
fig.set_size_inches(4, 3)

plt.show()
```

But this is not correct as is rendered :

[image]

How to render two plots or more side by side ?

Update :

Using code as per @Varun Balupuri answer :

```
from scipy.stats import norm
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import numpy as np

data = norm.rvs(10.0, 2.5, size=500)
mu, std = norm.fit(data)
plt.hist(data, bins=25, normed=True, alpha=0.6, color='g')
xmin, xmax = plt.xlim()
x = np.linspace(xmin, xmax, 100)
p = norm.pdf(x, mu, std)
plt.plot(x, p, 'k', linewidth=3)
title = "Fit results: mu = %.2f,  std = %.2f" % (mu, std)

plt.title(title)
fig = plt.gcf()
fig.set_size_inches(4, 3)

# plot in the first subplot
plt.subplot(1,2,1)

data = norm.rvs(10.0, 2.5, size=500)
mu, std = norm.fit(data)
plt.hist(data, bins=25, normed=True, alpha=0.6, color='g')


xmin, xmax = plt.xlim()
x = np.linspace(xmin, xmax, 100)
p = norm.pdf(x, mu, std)

# plot in the second subplot
plt.subplot(1, 2, 2)

plt.plot(x, p, 'k', linewidth=2)
title = "Fit results: mu = %.2f,  std = %.2f" % (mu, std)
plt.title(title)
fig = plt.gcf()
fig.set_size_inches(4, 3)

plt.show()
```

renders plot's side by side but are overlapping  , line is missing from left side chart , histogram is missing from right side chart :

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The approach to use `fig, axs = plt.subplots(1,2)` is correct. It will give you a figure `fig` and an array of axes `axs`.
What you need to do next is to *use* those axes explicitely. Instead of `plt.plot` you'd call `axs[0].plot()` to plot to the first axes and `axs[1].plot()` to plot to the second axes. The same for the `.hist` call.

Finally,you'd also want to set the title to each subplot individually, `axs[0].set_title(title)` instead of `plt.title(title)`.

Additionally the code below corrects the data limits for the pdf to use the axes limits of the subplots.

```
from scipy.stats import norm
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import numpy as np

fig, axs = plt.subplots(1,2, figsize=(5,3))

# first subplot is axs[0]
data = norm.rvs(10.0, 2.5, size=500)
mu, std = norm.fit(data)
axs[0].hist(data, bins=25, normed=True, alpha=0.6, color='g')
xmin, xmax = axs[0].get_xlim()
x = np.linspace(xmin, xmax, 100)
p = norm.pdf(x, mu, std)
axs[0].plot(x, p, 'k', linewidth=2)
title = "Fit results:\n mu = %.2f,\n  std = %.2f" % (mu, std)
axs[0].set_title(title)

# second subplot is axs[1]
data = norm.rvs(10.0, 2.5, size=500)
mu, std = norm.fit(data)
axs[1].hist(data, bins=25, normed=True, alpha=0.6, color='g')
xmin, xmax = axs[1].get_xlim()
x = np.linspace(xmin, xmax, 100)
p = norm.pdf(x, mu, std)
axs[1].plot(x, p, 'k', linewidth=2)
title = "Fit results:\n mu = %.2f,\n  std = %.2f" % (mu, std)
axs[1].set_title(title)

plt.tight_layout()
plt.show()
```

[image]

Answer (score 0):

You can use [subplot(nrows, ncols, plot_number)](https://matplotlib.org/api/pyplot_api.html?highlight=matplotlib%20pyplot%20subplot#matplotlib.pyplot.subplot), where nrows and ncols are used to notionally split the figure into nrows * ncols sub-axes, and plot_number is used to identify the particular subplot that this function is to create within the notional grid.

In your case, writing `plt.subplot(1,2,1)` and `plt.subplot(1, 2, 2)` prior to each plotting function to specify to plot a 1 row x 2 col grid. The third argument is which subplot you wish to plot in. See the below modification of your code:

```
from scipy.stats import norm
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import numpy as np

data = norm.rvs(10.0, 2.5, size=500)
mu, std = norm.fit(data)
plt.hist(data, bins=25, normed=True, alpha=0.6, color='g')
xmin, xmax = plt.xlim()
x = np.linspace(xmin, xmax, 100)
p = norm.pdf(x, mu, std)
plt.plot(x, p, 'k', linewidth=3)
title = "Fit results: mu = %.2f,  std = %.2f" % (mu, std)

plt.title(title)
fig = plt.gcf()
fig.set_size_inches(4, 3)

# plot in the first subplot
plt.subplot(1,2,1)

data = norm.rvs(10.0, 2.5, size=500)
mu, std = norm.fit(data)
plt.hist(data, bins=25, normed=True, alpha=0.6, color='g')


xmin, xmax = plt.xlim()
x = np.linspace(xmin, xmax, 100)
p = norm.pdf(x, mu, std)

# plot in the second subplot
plt.subplot(1, 2, 2)

plt.plot(x, p, 'k', linewidth=2)
title = "Fit results: mu = %.2f,  std = %.2f" % (mu, std)
plt.title(title)
fig = plt.gcf()
fig.set_size_inches(4, 3)

plt.show()
```

Comment: thanks but this does not render correctly, please see question update.

Comment: Using the object-oriented style (where you hold a reference to the figure and axes, rather than using `plt.gca()`, `plt.gcf()`, `plt.subplot(...)`) can make dealing with multiple plots vastly easier, because you just directly plot with `ax.hist(...)`, etc.